# Laravel send email to (notify) user using another email?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Some users have another email address that is stored as `secondary_email` column in `users` table.

How to send Notification using `$user->notify()` to this secondary email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would override the `toMail` method of your notification. For example:

```
use App\Mail\InvoicePaid as Mailable;

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return Mailable
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new Mailable($this->invoice))
           ->to($this->user->secondary_email ?? $this->user->email);
}
```

You can read more about formatting notifications [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#formatting-mail-messages).

Answer (score 2):

you can define a `routeNotificationForMail` method on the notifiable entity model

```
  public function routeNotificationForMail($notification)
    {
        // Return email address only...
        return $this->email_address;

        // Return email address and name...
        return [$this->email_address => $this->name];
    }
```

and then modify the function to suit your need. [laravel documentation notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#formatting-mail-messages)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but it's new to me.

I found a way to do this that met my needs a little better.  In our app, when a user changes their email address I keep their old email address active until they confirm the new one.

I wanted to use the `Notification` because it's the same email that I send for the original email confirmation.

```php
class EmailUpdate extends Notification
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $email;

    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $notifiable->email = $this->email ?? $notifiable->email;
        $url = config('app.site_url'). '/confirm/email/'. $notifiable->activation_code;

        return (new MailMessage())
            ->subject('My subject.')
            ->line('Hey ' . $notifiable->username . ', we received a request to change your email.')
            ->action('Verify Email Address', $url)
            ->line('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.');
    }
}
```

When I want to send the first confirmation I use

```php
$user->notify(new EmailUpdate);
```

When I want to notify them with the new email address I use

```php
$user->notify(new EmailUpdate($user->new_email));
```

Answer (score 0):

The documented solution using the `routeNotificationForMail` method is invalid for all cases, for example, when the email is changed in a specific notification only. Here we do not want to change the default email. as documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/notifications#customizing-the-recipient)

> ```
> class User extends Authenticatable
> {
>     use Notifiable;
>  
>     /**
>      * Route notifications for the mail channel.
>      *
>      * @return  array<string, string>|string
>      */
>     public function routeNotificationForMail(Notification $notification): array|string
>     {
>         // Return email address only...
>         return $this->email_address;
>  
>         // Return email address and name...
>         return [$this->email_address => $this->name];
>     }
> }
> ```

Avoiding the need to change the email using the `Mailable` class as in the selected answer, I have managed to overcome this situation by simply changing the `email` property of the user I'm sending the email to, as follows:

> ```
> $user->email = $user->alternative_email;
> $user->notify(new AlternativeEmailNotification());
> ```